# mysqli prepared statement without binding parameters still secure?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

it's my first post here and I'm also relatively new to the world of programming.
To make it short, while concluding my ecommerce site, developed with php, mysql and javascript/jquery, I've found out that the way I was building all my queries (with mysql_connect) could lead to mysql injections and a lot of other nasty things.

Trying to 'convert' everything to the more secure mysqli-prepared statements way, I've written a class containing all the methods I needed to retrieve informations from my database, but the way I'm not sure about the way I'm making the queries.

Some code: The class constructor

```
class Database {

    private $DBH;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->DBH = new mysqli(WEB_SERVER, WEB_USER, WEB_PASS, WEB_NAME);
        if ($this->DBH->connect_errno) {
            return "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $this->DBH->connect_errno . ") " . $this->DBH->connect_error;
            exit();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

...and a query example:

```
public function get_record_by_param($record, $param, $value) {
    $stmt = $this->getDBH()->stmt_init();

    $query = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM {$record} ";
    $query .= "WHERE {$param} = {$value} LIMIT 1";

    if($stmt->prepare($query)){
        return $this->execute_simpleAssoc($stmt);
    } else {
    return "Prepare failed: (" . $this->getDBH()->errno . ") " . $this->getDBH()->error;
    }
}
```

Using a query like this is still secure?
Or do I necessarily need to use the bind_param method?

Hoping I've not been confusing, thank you for any advice.

Comment: Not it is not, and yes you do. But you cannot bind the `$record` table name or the `$param` column name. Those should be compared against a whitelist of acceptable values.  Only the `$value` can be bound in your example above.

Comment: +1 for asking, this is soooo important

Answer (score 3):

Nope, it's not secure. mysqli can not parse what in your query string is (potentially vulnerable) data, and what is not.

If you want your data escaped, you will need to bind each parameter separately.

Bound parameters work for *data* only, however. For the column name, you will need to apply whitelisting as pointed out by @Michael in his comment. There is no way to automatically escape column/table names.

This applies to *all* database layers, including PDO. If you feed the layer a full query string, the data in it will **not** be magically escaped.

Comment: I kinda expected this answer, but.. how do I do this 'white-listing' thing? Could you tell me where to find some examples? The only thing that comes into my mind is to make another query, verifying if the provided column/table name is already in the database, but before to change everything I'd like to be a little more sure..

Comment: @piter yup, exactly, that's how it would work - find all column/table names, put them in an array, and do an `in_array()` on them

Comment: Ok, I'll try and post here the result. And thank you for 'super-fast' answering!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this more a terminology problem. Look, there are

- general concept of placeholders to represent your data in the query
- prepared statements, which being a subset of placeholders
- a binding thing, which belongs to prepared statements, but can be omitted

Most likely under "binding" you mean prepared statements. Answer may vary in this case.
But you take the idea of placeholders, the answers will change:
Your way of running queries of course remain insecure.
But it is possible to have perfectly secure query without (manual) bindings.
So, bind_param is not necessary.